# Re-execute or reload an EventListener

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm new to coding and I'm currently working on my first project where I'm building a web-based game using HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Here's my question using .addEventListener() that I couldn't seem to find a similar question (Might be because I didn't search the correct term so if it's been asked sorry in advance!).

So in my game I have couple buttons laid out, when the user clicks a button, the event listener will update the class and id of the clicked button. Theoretically, once the class and id are changed, it shouldn't listen to the event any longer, but it is. So let me give some sample codes first.

HTML

```
<button class="unclicked">1</button>
<button class="unclicked">2</button>
<button class="unclicked">3</button>
```

JavaScript

```
let testBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.unclicked')
for (const i of testBtns) {
  i.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.target.classList.replace('unclicked', 'clicked');
    testBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.unclicked')
 });
}
```

Ps. For the purpose of this question, I must use querySelectorAll(). Since the output of querySelectorAll is a NodeList, I was taught to use a for loop to iterate through the elements (Pls enlighten me if there's a better way.)

So with the code above, each button's class will be changed when the user clicks it, and then it will update testBtns (the element array). With each click the array will reduce eventually down to 0. However, this does not stop any of buttons from listening. I believe it is expected as the eventListener was initially assigned to the 3 buttons selected by using querySelectorAll().

I believe in order to limit the buttons that are listening to events, I will need to re-execute or refresh the event listener with the updated element array (testBtns). Is there a way to do that? Or, from my limited novice research it would appear that I may need to use removeEventListener()?

What is the best way to go about this?

Any advice is highly appreciated!!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already iterated over the elements and attached listeners to each of them by the time the click handler runs. Reassigning the `testBtns` doesn't do anything because the collection is already done with (and isn't referenced later).

If you wanted to do this by reassigning the collection, you could check if the clicked element is in the array before proceeding inside the listener:

```
let testBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll('.unclicked')];
for (const i of testBtns) {
  i.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (!testBtns.includes(i)) return;
    e.target.classList.replace('unclicked', 'clicked');
    testBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll('.unclicked')];
 });
}
```

But a much nicer approach would be to attach the event listener such that it can only fire once for each.

```
const testBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.unclicked')
for (const i of testBtns) {
  i.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.target.classList.replace('unclicked', 'clicked');
 }, { once: true }); // <-------
}
```

Or use event delegation to watch for clicks on `.unclicked` elements.

```
container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('.unclicked')) {
    e.target.classList.replace('unclicked', 'clicked');
  }
});
```

(where `container` is a container of which all buttons are descendants)

Comment: Might want to use `closest()` instead of `matches()` in case any of those buttons have child elements